# ui sref is not working in dropdown options

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a search text box on my page which shows the list of results onkeyup .I want to redirect the user on store page when he clicks on one of the options. So I included ui-sref in option tag along with ng-repeat; but nothing happens on clicking the response
This is my html code

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-9 navbar-right visible-lg">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-md label-control" placeholder="Search something..."
                           id="something" list="somethingelse" ng-model="search_text" ng-keyup="search(search_text)">
                     <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button"
                                tyle="background-color: #333;">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search glyphicon">
                                <div style="font-family: 'Montserrat';display: inline"> Search</div>
                            </i>
                            <label for="something">
                                <datalist id="somethingelse">
                                    <option ng-repeat="data in searchData"
                                            value="{{data.store_name | uppercase}}"
                                            ui-sref="store({storeName: data.store_name})">
                                    </option>
                                </datalist>
                            </label>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my app.js

```
.state('store', {
            url: '/store/:storeName',
            controller: 'StoreController',
            templateUrl: 'template/store.view.html',
            data: {
                authenticated: false,
                authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
            }
        })
```

Comment: You're binding it to an `option` element, where's the point in that?

Comment: I want that when i click on a option it should redirect to another page. What tag should I bind with ?

Comment: I think you should use a [dropdown](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown)

Comment: @AnshulAgarwal, ui-sref only works with an `<a>` tag, [as stated by the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref). You could, however, bind an `ng-click` to your option element, which would execute a `$state.go` function in your controller.